# Implementing multi-line php code with variables in function

Tags: php, function

The problem I have here is the automation of generating the. Basically the whole code is repeating in blocks and the only differences between these blocks are two variables. All the other parts of code are exactly the same and repeating. For this question, I represented the problem as custom colours of custom URLs, so it's more understandable. I assume it can be done in php.

I have this code but it's not working:

```
<?php

    function modal($color, $url)
    {
        echo '
            <div>
                <a style="color:'$color'" href='$url'>VISIT</a>
                <p>something something something - some other code lines, divs, buttons, etc</p>
            </div>
        ';
    }

    echo modal(red, "http://www.google.com");
    echo modal(green, "http://www.yahoo.com");
    echo modal(blue, "http://www.bing.com");

    ?>
```

That code should display three words VISIT in different colours, each word leads to a different URL.
Thank you very much for your time and help.

Comment: You are probably getting some errors as it should be `' . $color. '` (same for `$url`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- I assume that `red`, `green`, and `blue` are constants that are defined using `define()` - in which case they should have `UPPERCASE` names to indicate they're constants.
- Your code isn't working because you need to use the string concatenation operator (a dot `.`) OR use interpolated strings. My code below uses concatenation.
- You need to enclose the `href` attribute value in quotes (technically speaking, this is only required if the value could result in ambiguous HTML, but it's always a good idea to enclose all attribute values in quotes).
- You also need to HTML-encode your values too. Use `htmlentities` for this. Otherwise a `>` or  `&` (very common) character in a URL will break your HTML rendering and introduce a risk of an XSS attack.

```
function modal( $color, $url ) {
    echo '
            <div>
                <a style="color:' . htmlentities( $color ) . ';" href="' . htmlentities( $url ) . '">VISIT</a>
                <p>something something something - some other code lines, divs, buttons, etc</p>
            </div>
        ';
}
```

You also may want to consider using HEREDOC or NOWDOC for multi-line string literals.